# Cannot read property 'description' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am in the process of learning EmberJS using the Ember CLI, but I am having trouble displaying a fixture model in my template

router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('calendars', {path: '/'}, function () {
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

templates/calendars.hbs

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="list-group">
    {{#each calendar in model}}
      <li>{{calendar.name}}</li>
    {{/end}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

routes/calendars.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('calendar');
  }
});
```

models/calendar.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Calendar = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

Calendar.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {id: 1, name: 'myCalendar'},
    {id: 2, name: 'mySecondCalendar'}
  ]
});

export default Calendar;
```

adapters/application.js

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

However, when I visit the root URL /, the server crashes with the following error message

```
File: nodecal/templates/calendars.hbs
Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: Is `name: DS.attr('strinf')` in `models/calendar.js` accurate, or a transcription typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your closing tag in your template is incorrect](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1846). Change it to this:

```
{{#each calendar in model}}
  <li>{{calendar.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```